# What causes EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property?

Tags: 7, organic-groups, entities

I have added new field to my bundle in one of entity type. I used the Group audience as field type and Group Audience as widget type.
This is to make the field to select multiple records.

While adding the new record with all the values it gives following error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property og_membership.
>   in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 354 of
>   /var/www/vhosts/test1.3blmedia.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

I am not getting where it is wrong. Any hints?

Comment: Are you using og_audience module? It is quite old so probably not support entity metadata wrapper.

Comment: @JimmyKo Yes I am using Group Audience Widget but it is working well in other modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please login to admin and go to following page. You need to add field for your bundle. It will resolve above error.

Home » Administration » Configuration » Group
Organic groups field settings

For more details please visit following link.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2023721

Answer (score 0):

If it is a custom field that you have defined in your module (using `hook_field_info()`) then you need to add a `property_type` to your field info.  See https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/property-info-for-fields for an example and https://www.drupal.org/node/905580 for a full list of possible types.

If your field is a complex (multiple value) data structure you may also additionally need to include `property_callbacks` as well.  See http://d7.thecarneyeffect.co.uk/describe-field-properties-make-custom-fields-work-entity-metadata-wrappers for a good example of this.